# Creating a random number with constant value within groups

Tags: r, merge

I'm creating a random number where each member of a specific group has the same value of the variable. I found a solution but I suspect it isn't very efficient. I'm wondering if anyone anyone has a way to do this in one line of code:

```
library(dplyr)
data(mtcars)

t1 <- Sys.time() #Can the next two lines be replaced by one?

a <- data.frame(random = runif(3, 0, 6),
                cyl = seq(4,8,2))

merged <- merge(mtcars, a, by = 'cyl')
t2 <- Sys.time()
t2 - t1
#check to make sure it worked
merged %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  summarise(across(random, sd))
```

Comment: Does `mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% group_modify(function(.x, .y) .x %>% mutate(random=runif(1, 0, 6))) ` give you what you're looking for?  Note the use of `1` as the first argument of the call to `runif` to ensure recycling across all rows of the group.

Comment: Yes your approach worked as well. In terms of speed, your approach was slowest (0.031 seconds), followed by mine (0.015), and then the solution of @jay.sf (0.006).

Comment: Yes, the tidyverse is often (relatively) slow compared to other approaches.  For me, it's major advantage is clarity: with well-chosen object names, code can be virtually self-documenting.  That's a huge bonus when it comes to maintenance.  If speed becomes an issue, then by all means look elsewhere.  <Inserts tongue in cheek>However, if 25 thousanths of a second is important to you, then your life is busier than mine!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One-liner using `ave`.

```
res <- transform(mtcars, rand=ave(cyl, cyl, FUN=\(x) runif(1)))
```

Check:

```
with(res, tapply(rand, list(cyl), var))
# 4 6 8 
# 0 0 0
```